# Docker + Yesod Linking Failure

Tags: haskell, linker, docker, yesod, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a Dockerized Yesod application, and I've initialized the Yesod project under the directory `./my-app`. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM haskell:7.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq5 libpq-dev
RUN cabal update

ADD my-app /opt/my-app

WORKDIR /opt/my-app

RUN cabal sandbox delete
RUN cabal sandbox init
RUN cabal install -j --only-dependencies
RUN cabal build

RUN dist/build/db-import/db-import

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["dist/build/my-app/my-app", "production", "-p", "3000"]
```

When I actually go to run docker, it's able to build all the dependencies, but I get a linker error:

```
/opt/my-app/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4/cryptonite-0.3/libHScryptonite-0.3.a(generic.o):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `gmtab'
/opt/my-app/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4/cipher-aes-0.2.10/libHScipher-aes-0.2.10.a(aes_generic.o):(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do here, because I've tried this with `haskell:latest` and `haskell:7.10` but I still end up with the same error. I'm not sure whether it's the fact that the specific container OS is Ubuntu or not. I'd love to hear suggestions on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really look like a docker problem.  It just looks like two libraries you're trying to use provide the same symbol.

Comment: Thanks larsks. I actually ran `cabal build` on the project itself without the Dockerfile and it builds perfectly fine. I don't get this linking error that I get when using the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm fairly certain @larsks is right, and cabal is just choosing different versions of libraries. I'd recommend using a Stackage snapshot (or building with stack).

Comment: Hi @MichaelSnoyman, after tons of fiddling with the yesod scaffolded `.cabal` file and with stackage I managed to get it working. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelSnoyman stated, fiddling with stackage and changing the cabal file dependency for yesod-static to `== 1.5.0` got the container to build.